# Embeddable EmbeddedId generated a new table/entty

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, jpa, composite-primary-key

I'm not sure what is the reason why this code creates a new table.
The `LockDatabaseRecordKeyId` is supposed to be the composite key of the `LockDatabaseRecordKey` entity but during build, it automatically creates another table.

```
@Embeddable
open class LockDatabaseRecordKeyId : Serializable {
    @Column(name = "database_record_id")
    lateinit var databaseRecordId: UUID

    @Column(name = "key_id")
    lateinit var keyId: UUID

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (other == null) return false
        return (other is HouseKeyId) && other.databaseRecordId == this.databaseRecordId && other.keyId == this.keyId
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return "${databaseRecordId}.${keyId}".hashCode()
    }
}
```

and this is the `LockDatabaseRecordKey` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lock_database_record_keys",
        uniqueConstraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(columnNames = arrayOf("database_record_id", "key_id"))
        ]
)
open class LockDatabaseRecordKey
{
    // No column is generated for this value
    @EmbeddedId
    lateinit var id: LockDatabaseRecordKeyId

    @MapsId("databaseRecordId")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = LockDatabaseRecord::class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE])
    @JoinColumn(name = "database_record_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    lateinit var lockDatabaseRecord: LockDatabaseRecord

    @MapsId("keyId")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Key::class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE])
    @JoinColumn(name = "key_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    lateinit var key: Key

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Lock::class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE])
    @JsonIgnore
    lateinit var lock: Lock
```

For some reason it creates the table `lock_database_record_lock_database_record_keys`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to annotate `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lockDatabaseRecord")` on the `lockDatabaseRecordKeys: Set<LockDatabaseRecordKey>` field in `LockDatabaseRecord`.